# React dynamically adding classes for animation reverse

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, frontend

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j4r7yoollw
I animate the modal on button click. But I want to be able to reverse the animation in `components/Modal/index.css` when I close it. I implemented `setTimeout` to give the modal time to fade out but it doesn't work. How do I do that so it does work?

Modal/index.js:

```html
import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Success from './Success';
import './index.css';

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      success: false,
      reverse: false,
    };
  }
  removeUser = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // simulate async loading action
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          success: true,
        }),
      2000,
    );
    //simulate promise (function above then this below)
    setTimeout(() => this.props.removeUser(this.props.data), 2001);
  };
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ reverse: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.closeModal();
      this.setState({
        reverse: false,
        success: false,
      });
    }, 3000);
  };
  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props.data;
    const { loading, success } = this.state;
    // The gray background
    const backdropStyle = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
      padding: 50,
    };

    // The modal "window"
    const modalStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      textAlign: 'center',
      borderRadius: 3,
      maxWidth: 360,
      minHeight: 130,
      margin: '0 auto',
    };

    if (this.props.displayModal) {
      return (
        <div className={'backdrop ' + (this.state.reverse ? 'reverse' : '')} style={backdropStyle}>
          <div className={'modal ' + (this.state.reverse ? 'reverse' : '')} style={modalStyle}>
            {!loading &&
              !success && (
                <Question
                  id={id}
                  name={name}
                  removeUser={this.removeUser}
                  closeModal={this.closeModal}
                />
              )}
            {loading && !success && <Loading />}
            {!loading && success && <Success closeModal={this.closeModal} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Modal/index.css:

```html
@keyframes modalFade {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal {
  animation-name: modalFade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes backdropFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.backdrop {
  animation-name: backdropFade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

.reverse {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code inside question

Comment: @artgb done, full code in codesandbox

Comment: Just noticed in Devtools that "reverse" is getting added to className, so I was wondering if it is the CSS that needs work? I am also learning.

Comment: @anand yes I think css animation is not started again when I just add class with `animation-direction: reverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes in your code and, as far as I tested, it's working fine.

In the css file, i've added a new animation for reverse modes to ensure the other animation, normal directioned, was canceled.
I've also added `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` property to keep animation freezed on last frame.

In the jsx file, I've changed the timeout from 3000 to 300ms to match the animation duration 0.3s.

I've forked you at https://codesandbox.io/s/5wlooq88xl with those corrections.

```js
closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ reverse: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.closeModal();
      this.setState({
        reverse: false,
        success: false,
      });
    }, 300);
  };
```

```css
@keyframes modalFade {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes modalFadeReverse {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal {
  animation-name: modalFade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.modal.reverse {
  animation-name: modalFadeReverse;
}

@keyframes backdropFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes backdropFadeReverse {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.backdrop {
  animation-name: backdropFade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.backdrop.reverse {
  animation-name: backdropFadeReverse;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!